# Cannot find module './my_module'

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Когда я загружаю песню в базу данных, то перенаправляю себя на главную страницу, где выводятся все песни, но я получаю вот такую ошибку: `Cannot find module './my_song.mp3'`, хотя после перезагрузки страницы все работает без ошибок

**Получаю песни с базы данных**

```
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const token = this.$store.getters["auth/getToken"];
      const { result, ok } = await this.$store.dispatch("user/getData", {
        data: ["songs"],
        token,
      });

      let songs = [];

      if (ok) {
        songs = result.songs.map((song) => {
          song.active = false;
          // Думаю, что ошибка здесь
          song.audio = new Audio(require(`@/uploads/${song.file}`).default);
          song.currentTime = 0;
          song.audio.volume = this.getVolume;
          song.volume = this.getVolume;

          return song;
        });
      }

      this.$store.commit("setSongs", songs);

      if (localStorage.getItem("volume")) {
        this.$store.commit(
          "setVolume",
          JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("volume"))
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Сделайте ```song.audio = new Audio(require(`@/uploads/${song.file}`).default);``` отдельной async-функцией, должно заработать. После перезагрузки она берётся из кеша или из-за того, что соединение уже прогрето достаточно быстро.

Comment: @DraKoan, спасибо большое, что помогли, правда сработало

Comment: тогда оформлю как ответ. Принимайте его :)

Comment: На самом деле вы практически сами обнаружили ошибку, просто немного опыта не хватило осознать её механизм. Я несколько дней ломал голову в своё время когда пытался менять таблицу стилей, которая не успевала подгружаться.

Comment: Наврал. В том моём проекте слишком быстро после перезагрузки подгружались сами скрипты, требующие в себя таблицы стилей, которые просто не успевали отработаться браузером (вопрос 20-30 мс) и требуемая анимация не запускалась, а выдавала ошибку. А при обычной загрузке с почищенным кэшом всё работало. То есть ситуация может быть диаметрально противоположная при той же ошибке неучёта задержек работы железа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
song.audio = new Audio(require(`@/uploads/${song.file}`).default);
```

Должна быть отдельной async-функцией.

После перезагрузки песня берётся из кеша или из-за того, что соединение уже прогрето достаточно быстро. А до перезагрузки скрипт не успевает её получить прямо в потоке исполнения, и отдаёт undefined.